# require: 'ngModel' in Angular 6/7+

Tags: angular

I'm working on a simple upper/lower case directive. Since I use ControlValueAccessor I would like to be able to require ngModel directive on a same host element where I apply my appCaseTo directive.

Is there way to do that in Angular?

How to require presence of certain directive from another directive?

Similar to AngularJS with `require: 'ngModel'` approach.

```
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upper-lower-case-directive?file=src/app/case-to.directive.ts) project.

Comment: Q: So you want to use AngularJS syntax for the AngularJS binding model with Angular 6/7?

Comment: @paulsm4 No, I don't want to use same syntax. I'm looking for a solution to make sure that my directive is applied to an element on which there is ngModel directive too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you could "include" ngModel into you selector, like so:

```
  selector: '[ngModel][appCaseTo]',
```

Comment: This can work. However I don't want to modify my selector, only if that is the only way to make sure both directives are there.

Comment: Well, the selector is the representation of your directive in the template. With the Syntax from my Answer, you are requiring that the Input-Element also has an Attribute "ngModel" (it does, however, not enforce that this Atrribute ist the ngModel from the Angular Forms-Module)

Comment: Thank you. Probably this is the simplest solution. Also I think in an Angular app every time you have ngModel as an attribute it will be picked by the framework.